# Possible reasons why UIGestureRecognizer is not firing?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a subclassed `UIView`, let's call it `TileView.m/h`.

In `TileView.m`, I have the following code: (`[setup]` is definitely being called, I checked with breakpoints).

```
- (void)setup {
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(testPressed:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)testPressed:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"tap pressed");
}
```

For some reason, the `testPressed` method is not called when I tap the view!

Strangely, if I copy the `TileView` class into a blank xCode project and set it up there, everything works absolutely fine. This is peculiar since gestures are handled first by subviews and then by superviews - so the tile class shouldn't be affected by its superviews. Also the gesture is fully contained within the `TileView` class.

For reference, the tile view is nested fairly deeply in a:
`Controller -> controller's view -> scroll view -> container view -> tile view` pattern.

I have tried without success:

- Setting userInteractionEnabled = YES on TileView and all its subviews.
- Removing all gesture recognizers from other parts of code to avoid interference.
- Setting `tap.delegate = self` and then implementing `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneously...` to always `return YES;`

No luck :/

Any ideas for what else could be going wrong? Or what tests can I run to understand the problem  in more detail?

**EDIT: More details**

Recall that the tile view is nested in: `Controller -> controller's view -> scroll view -> container view -> tile view`

If I add a gesture recognizer in the controller file with:

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]
```

and then use `[self.view hitTest:[sender locationInView:self.view] withEvent:nil];` in the event handler, I can see that the returned view is a `UIScrollView` and not a `TileView` as would be expected.

Additionally, adding the gesture recognizer to `self.scrollView` instead works fine, but stops working if I add it to `self.containerView` (which is the only subview of `scrollView`). `containerView` has `userInteractionEnabled = YES`.

Comment: Did you forget [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1]; ?

Comment: I just tried this - it hasn't done the trick unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure the `setup` method is being called?

Comment: Yes, I added breakpoints in the setup method. It's definitely being called.

Comment: Could it be that your TileView is outside the bounds of its superview?  Try setting clipToBounds to YES for the scroll view and/or container view and see if TileView disappears.

Comment: Fantastic! That was it! When I created the composite view, I used `alloc] init]` and then never set the frame property. Thanks rdelmar.

Answer (score 9):

If the view contains subviews that are `UIImageView`s, remember that you have to explicitly set the `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES` (the default is `NO`).

If not, the image views will prevent the tap from reaching the superview.

Also, remember to set the number of touches.

Comment: None of the subviews are UIImageViews - (there are some UILabels and other UIViews). However, even when I looped through the subviews and set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on all of them, it still isn't working. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check that you're not trying to reuse the `UITapGestureRecognizer` object for different views.

It seems like it's possible because you're just appending the gesture to the view, but in ultimately the view needs to be assigned to the view property on the gesture object so adding the gesture object to a second view will just overwrite the first.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its not firing is because you are not keeping a reference to your `UITapGestureRecognizer`. As soon as `setup` function returns your `UITapGestureRecognizer` gets deallocated.
If you want it to work save it to a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;

- (void)setup {
    self.tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                         action:@selector(testPressed:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}

- (void)testPressed:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    NSLog(@"tap pressed");
}
```